# How to p/invoke side-by-side assembly from .NET Core on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke

Doing p/invoke with [side-by-side assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/SbsCs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-) in "old" .NET requires assembly manifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="..."
          version="..."
          processorArchitecture="x86"
          publicKeyToken="..."
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

otherwise `[DllImport]` can't find DLL.

.NET Core apps, AFAIK, can't handle `dependentAssembly` from `app.config`.

Is there any way to load side-by-side assembly in .NET Core app on Windows and use p/invoke?

Comment: Wouldn't that be possible with a sxs app manifest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests ? after all, this is more a windows binding issue than a .NET issue? Do you have a real/simple example at hand?

Comment: @SimonMourier, do you mean to create *.manifest file for application executable instead of changing something in app.config? Maybe it will wok... I didn't ever think about this. At the moment I have no real example, but I'll try with manifest file a little later.

Comment: Hmm... it's not a perfect solution - it looks like it won't work with in-proc hosting model for ASP .NET Core apps, since app executable is IIS service.

Comment: The runtime section of web.config seems still supported for asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configuration-sections-of-webconfig-2 see also https://blog.rytmis.net/2016/03/29/asp-net-core-and-assembly-binding-redirects/